SwiftUI's `refreshable` closure captures `self` only once
It appears that refreshable closure captures copy of self dead tight on first View initialization and never recreates itself on body invocations.
Here's minimal reproducible example:
import SwiftUI
import Observation

@Observable
final class Model {
    let id: Int
    init(id: Int) { self.id = id }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    let m1 = Model(id: 1)
    let m2 = Model(id: 2)
    @State private var one: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Choosen", isOn: self.$one)
            ChildView(m: self.one ? self.m1 : self.m2)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let m: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Model \(self.m.id)")
        }
        .refreshable {
            print("\(self.m.id)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ParentView().padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

It's defenitely a bug. Is there anything we can do now?

This is the kind of bug that makes you lose all confidence in SwiftUI!

If we get this re-opened I'll post a simple one-liner workaround for your sample code: .id(m.id) before .refreshable.

@malhal We will lose identity of ChildView then. For now i'm settled with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76630712/826716

refreshable is known for not being unreliable, I created my own about a year ago. You have to combine refreshable with task(id:)
